# imagettftext giving weird results

Tags: php, drawing, imagettftext

Trying to draw some text on an already existing image in php, but get weird results.

I have this image [image]

and I'm trying to draw a number on it with white text, but I get this result [image]

Here is the code:

```
<?php


    $font = "files/fonts/open_sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('images/icons/marker_icon.png'); 
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,255);
    imagettftext($image, 1, 1, 1, 1, $white, $font, $_GET['count']);
    header("content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);


?>
```

First time drawing on an image, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Since there is a lot of transparency in my image, I had to set `imageAlphaBlending` to `true`:

```
    <?php
            $font = "files/fonts/open_sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf";
            $image = imagecreatefrompng('images/icons/marker_icon.png'); 
            $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,255);


            imageAlphaBlending($image, true);
            imageSaveAlpha($image, true);


            imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 10, 35, $white, $font, $_GET['count']);
            header("content-type: image/png");
            imagepng($image);
            imagedestroy($image);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was your image, I'm not sure how or why but it was messed up. I opened it in a photo editor and resaved it with a different name as a PNG and it worked. Also, your text won't show up because your font size is set to one and it begins at xy 1,1. It should reflect as below:

```
<?php
    $font = "files/fonts/open_sans/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf";
    $image = imagecreatefrompng('images/icons/marker_icon.png'); 
    $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255,255,255);
    imagettftext($image, 15, 0, 10, 35, $white, $font, $_GET['count']);
    header("content-type: image/png");
    imagepng($image);
    imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

[PHP Manual imagettftext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

Comment: What photo editor did you use? I'm using photoshop and I tried this and it didn't work.

Comment: Paint haha. Maybe it has to do with the colors photoshop is using.